# Change Displayname of list columns via powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell

This code works fine.

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://xxx
 $listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::GenericList 
 $spListCollection = $spWeb.Lists 
 $spListCollection.Add("ExternalSites","External Sites",$listTemplate)
 $spList = $spWeb.GetList("/Lists/ExternalSites")
 $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text 
 $spList.Fields.Add("ExtSiteUrl",$spFieldType,$false)
 $spList.Fields.Add("ExtSiteDescription",$spFieldType,$false)
 $spList.Update()
```

However the Add method receives the display name, if I change those to.
External Site Url
and External Site Description

Then the internal names dont match anymore.
They are something like:

External_x0020_Site_x0020_Url
External_x0020_Site_x0020_Descri

I want to be able to change at least the displayname via powershell but leave the internal name as: ExtSiteUrl and ExtSiteDescription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the title of the field would be the display name of the field and the internal name will not be changed since it will be used for programmatic purposes. Change the title property and you will be able to change the display name.

You can try changing this - `$spList.Fields["External Site Desc"].Title`